# unable to fetch process time using sigar

Tags: java, netbeans, sigar, policyfiles

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.hyperic.sigar.*;

public class SigarDemo {

public static void main(String args[]) throws SigarException, IOException
{

    final Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
    final long[] processes = sigar.getProcList();
    ProcTime pt=new ProcTime();
    for (final long processId : processes)  {
    ProcUtil.getDescription(sigar, processId);
    pt=sigar.getProcTime(processId);       
    System.out.println("---"+pt.getStartTime());
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch process time of each process using sigar. I am getting this errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at taskmanager.SigarDemo.main(SigarDemo.java:22)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sigar.nativeLogging" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1294)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:714)
at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.(Sigar.java:78)
```

I have tried policy file setting all permission. but still I am getting errors. I am using netbeans 8.0 . and I had already setting

`-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=src/dir1/dir2/important.policy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code to get the process times

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        final Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
        final long[] processes = sigar.getProcList();
        ProcTime pt = new ProcTime();
        for (final long processId : processes) {
            try {
                ProcUtil.getDescription(sigar, processId);
                pt = sigar.getProcTime(String.valueOf(processId));
                System.out.println("---" + pt.getStartTime());
            } catch (SigarException e) {
                System.out.println("can't accessible...");
            }

        }

    } catch (SigarException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

you don't want to specify the security policy file in VM arguments to get the process times. but the thing is `getProcTime()` will not return process times for *some process* ids because of `SigarPermissionDeniedException`.

but you will get process time for *some processes* without any problem.

I got this idea from a sample demo file from `bindings\java\examples` folder. I posted it below with slight modification. you can compile and run it to see the result(it includes the process time also)

```
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarProxy;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;
import org.hyperic.sigar.ProcCredName;
import org.hyperic.sigar.ProcMem;
import org.hyperic.sigar.ProcTime;
import org.hyperic.sigar.ProcState;
import org.hyperic.sigar.ProcUtil;
import org.hyperic.sigar.cmd.Shell;
import org.hyperic.sigar.cmd.SigarCommandBase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Show process status.
 */
public class Ps extends SigarCommandBase {

    public Ps(Shell shell) {
        super(shell);
    }

    public Ps() {
        super();
    }

    protected boolean validateArgs(String[] args) {
        return true;
    }

    public String getSyntaxArgs() {
        return "[pid|query]";
    }

    public String getUsageShort() {
        return "Show process status";
    }

    public boolean isPidCompleter() {
        return true;
    }

    public void output(String[] args) throws SigarException {
        long[] pids;
        if (args.length == 0) {
            pids = this.proxy.getProcList();
        }
        else {
            pids = this.shell.findPids(args);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<pids.length; i++) {
            long pid = pids[i];
            try {
                output(pid);
            } catch (SigarException e) {
                this.err.println("Exception getting process info for " +
                                 pid + ": " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static String join(List info) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        Iterator i = info.iterator();
        boolean hasNext = i.hasNext();
        while (hasNext) {
            buf.append((String)i.next());
            hasNext = i.hasNext();
            if (hasNext)
                buf.append("\t");
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }

    public static List getInfo(SigarProxy sigar, long pid)
        throws SigarException {

        ProcState state = sigar.getProcState(pid);
        ProcTime time = null;
        String unknown = "???";

        List info = new ArrayList();
        info.add(String.valueOf(pid));

        try {
            ProcCredName cred = sigar.getProcCredName(pid);
            info.add(cred.getUser());
        } catch (SigarException e) {
            info.add(unknown);
        }

        try {
            time = sigar.getProcTime(pid);
            info.add(getStartTime(time.getStartTime()));
            System.out.println("this line has executed..!!!");
        } catch (SigarException e) {
            info.add(unknown);
        }

        try {
            ProcMem mem = sigar.getProcMem(pid);
            info.add(Sigar.formatSize(mem.getSize()));
            info.add(Sigar.formatSize(mem.getRss()));
            info.add(Sigar.formatSize(mem.getShare()));
        } catch (SigarException e) {
            info.add(unknown);
        }

        info.add(String.valueOf(state.getState()));

        if (time != null) {
            info.add(getCpuTime(time));
        }
        else {
            info.add(unknown);
        }

        String name = ProcUtil.getDescription(sigar, pid);
        info.add(name);

        return info;
    }

    public void output(long pid) throws SigarException {
        println(join(getInfo(this.proxy, pid)));
    }

    public static String getCpuTime(long total) {
        long t = total / 1000;
        return t/60 + ":" + t%60;
    }

    public static String getCpuTime(ProcTime time) {
        return getCpuTime(time.getTotal());
    }

    private static String getStartTime(long time) {
        if (time == 0) {
            return "00:00";
        }
        long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String fmt = "MMMd";

        if ((timeNow - time) < ((60*60*24) * 1000)) {
            fmt = "HH:mm";
        }

        return new SimpleDateFormat(fmt).format(new Date(time));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Ps().processCommand(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: but my actual problem is how to avoid "SigarExceptionPermissionDenied" ? i know .. i should write policy file for permission. but how to write it and where to post ?